# image not saved while updating userprofile in django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to update a userprofile model  that i used to save additional information over the inbuilt User model,  now when i am trying to update it , the image does not gets saved. I need help to resolve this issue

```
# In views.py 
@login_required(login_url=LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
def update_user_profile(request):
    userobj = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
    form = UserProfileForm(data = request.POST or None,files= request.FILES or None, instance=userobj)
    if request.method=='POST':
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.picture = form.cleaned_data['picture']
            profile.about = form.cleaned_data['about']
            profile.save()
        else:
            print("NO picure")
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/blog/profile/")

    return render(request, "blog/post_update.html", {'form':form})

#models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user    = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_images/", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)


#In forms.py
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['about'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control '})
        self.fields['picture'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control-file'})
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('about', 'picture')

# userprofileform.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create Profile">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

please take a look at the code and help.  while registering if the image was uploaded it get's saved , but when i try to update the userprofile directly in profile section image  does not get changed and shows the same as one saved while user registration  else it shows None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes on templates in settings.py and got my project runnning. Issue was that i was not mentioning the Templates directory properly